# two intervals color df panda red <-3 and green >3

Tags: python, pandas, styles, highlight, intervals

I would like to know how to generate two intervals for my highlight.
I want all the value of my df <-3 in red and all the value >3 in green, else don't change, in black.

I try with highlight_between and other, but never work :

```
cm = sns.light_palette("blue", as_cmap = True)
df = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, low = -0.2, high = 0.5, text_color_threshold = 0.6 ).set_precision(2)
df.style.highlight_between(left = 3, right = 10, color="green")\
.style.highlight_between(left = -10, right = -3, color="red")
df = df.style.highlight_min(color = 'red', axis=None)
df = df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background-color:lime" if i>3 \
                      elif "background-color:tomato" if i<-3 else "background-color:black" for i in x],
               ) ## Axis=1 : Row and Axis=0: Column
```

I think my problem is to add multiple style for one df.

An exemple of what I tried :

```py
def highlight(val):
    green = 'background-color: green' if val > 3 else ''
    red = 'background-color: red' if val < -3 else ''
    return green, red

df.style.applymap(highlight)
```

the red part don't work but just green give me that :

[image: screenshot_result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.rand(5,10) - 0.5) * 20)

df.style.applymap(lambda x: f"background-color: {'lime' if x > 3 else 'tomato' if x < -3 else 'white'}")
```

[image]

You can also chain styles like that to produce the same result:

```
df.style.applymap(lambda x: f"background-color: {'lime' if x > 3 else ''}")\
        .applymap(lambda x: f"background-color: {'tomato' if x < -3 else ''}")
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I ask an other question, it's the continuity of this one because I don't have the place in this comment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73473910/mutiple-style-for-one-dataframe-issues.