# Mutiple style for one DataFrame issues

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styles, apply

I would like to understand how "style" works in python, I always have the same error :
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute ....

```py
df_x = team_table()

df_x1 = df_x[1:].style.applymap(lambda x: f"background-color: {'#28D1C5' if x > 2 else ''}")\
        .applymap(lambda x: f"background-color: {'#FFC33C' if x < -2 else ''}")\
        .format(precision=2)  

df_x0 = df_x.style.apply(lambda x: x.index.map({"Participants":'background-color: #FFFFA7'}))\
            .format(precision=2)
```

for now, I manage to have :

- the first row in yellow but not the conditional formatting (df_x0)
- and the conditional formatting blue and orange cells but the first row disappear because I am obligate to apply style on df_x[1:] otherwise I have TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. (df_x1)

The result I want:

[image: result I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the value is a [number](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html): if not make a yellow background, otherwise apply colors as usual:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numbers

np.random.seed(0)
df = (pd.DataFrame([list('abcdef')] + ((np.random.rand(5,6) - 0.5) * 10).tolist()))

df.style.applymap(lambda x: 
    f"background-color: {'#FFFFA7' if not isinstance(x, numbers.Number) else '#28D1C5' if x > 2 else '#FFC33C' if x < -2 else 'white'}"
    ).format(precision=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a solution not using this "trick", because I have other style to apply and don't know how to multiply style ?

Comment: can you give an example of what you need (or better ask this as a new question)? Instead of a lambda you can use a regular function where you can easier write complex conditions.

Comment: Sorry for the late but here is a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73517737/mutilple-style-on-part-of-dataframe-with-two-columns-levels, when I use a regular function I have the error "styler object is not subscriptable", I cannot re-use a df who already have a style